# C++/C GST trace GstElement life cycle

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I am building a quite involved gstreamer application, which tries to reuse parts of the pipeline if possible. Anyways, I have the suspicion that the pipelines are not cleaned properly because the process keeps piling up file descriptiors and does not release them.

I suspect that the refcounted pipeline `GstElement` (and subsequently `filesource`) is somehow kept alive, because I am messing up the refcount. To ease debugging, is there a way to either:

- Add a callback of some sort that is invoked before the ref count reaches 0, so I can make sure that all pipelines are properly destroyed?
- Get the list of all global existing `GstElement` through some context of some sort?

Comment: Choose one language. Is it C, or C++?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ I would suggest to use simple RAII wrappers which helps with resource lifetime management. An example:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <auto Fn>
using FunctionObj = std::integral_constant<decltype(Fn), Fn>;

template <typename T, auto Fun>
using ResourceReleasedByFunction = std::unique_ptr<T, FunctionObj<Fun>>;

template <typename T, auto Fun>
void AddressOfPtr(T* rsc) {
  Fun(&rsc);
}

using ScopedGstElement = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GstElement, gst_object_unref>;
using ScopedGstCaps = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GstCaps, gst_caps_unref>;
using ScopedGstSample = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GstSample, gst_sample_unref>;
using ScopedGstBuffer = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GstBuffer, gst_buffer_unref>;
using ScopedGstPad = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GstPad, gst_object_unref>;
using ScopedGstBus = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GstBus, gst_object_unref>;

using ScopedGChar = ResourceReleasedByFunction<gchar, g_free>;
using ScopedGError = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GError, AddressOfPtr<GError, g_clear_error>>;
using ScopedGMainContext = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GMainContext, g_main_context_unref>;
using ScopedGMainLoop = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GMainLoop, g_main_loop_unref>;
```

An example usage:

```
ScopedGstElement pipeline{gst_pipeline_new("mypipeline")};
ScopedGstElement camerasource{gst_element_factory_make("v4l2src", "v4l2src")};
ScopedGstElement videoconvert{gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "videoscale")};
ScopedGstElement videosink{gst_element_factory_make("fakesink", "fakesink")};

gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline.get()), camerasource.release(), videoconvert.release(), videosink.release(), nullptr);
```

Thanks to that you do not need to remember to clean the resource or even when you remember you may call an invalid function, for instance `gst_object_unref` instead of `gst_buffer_unref`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Once the element is added to the bin or the pipeline responsibility is taken by that parent. If the parent is destroyed correctly then the element also will be destroyed.

to destroy the pipeline you can follow this.

```
{
   GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("mystuff")
   .
   .
   .
   // Do your stuff here
   gst_element_send_event(GST_ELEMENT(pipeline), gst_event_new_eos());
   gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT(pipeline), GST_STATE_NULL);
   gst_object_unref (pipeline);
}
```

Comment: Yes my problem is that the suspicion is that the pipeline itsself has pending refrences. Also does your answer hold true if I somehow manage to still hold a refrence to a pipeline element?

Comment: You can check the reference count with GST_TRACE